# Missing Bootcamp partition

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, dual-boot

I use to have a Bootcamp partition, which was about 100Gb, but it has disappeared from the boot options and I am not sure if it still exists on my HD. I am looking to sell this iMac, so I was going to try and remove this partition anyway, but I don't want to sell it if someone could recover it and access my login.

I have been trying *Disk Utility > First Aid* on the drive

I have also been running `/sbin/fsck -fy` in Single User mode.

This is the current situation of my HDD.

1. Does the Windows partition still exist?
2. As I didn't remove the partition/windows installation properly from BootCamp Assistant, can it be recovered?
3. If I perform the *Recovery > Re-install MacOS* for the sale, will this wipe the entire 1TB disk properly?

[image]

EDIT

After running `diskutil ap resizecontainer disk2 0b` I am getting the error `object map is invalid`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no windows partition on your disk, but there's 100g lost (old windows partition may be).
To recover this 100g and add it to the Mac Os volume, try this command :

`diskutil ap resizecontainer disk2 0b`

Comment: Thanks @Jean_JD. I have run this command and getting an error, above.

Comment: May be you need boot in Recovery Mode and with Disk Utility, do a First Aid on the Fusion drive.